# Flutter share link to other apps with a separate description

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using the flutter share_plus library to share dynamic links for a refer a friend feature.
In the pop-up dialogue box, I want to be able to add a description that is separate from the link being shared, to explain what is happening to the user. Is there a way to do this with share_plus or is there another library I can use that has this functionality?

[image]

In the photo, where it currently says Share, I was wondering if there is any way to edit that.

Edit: I am aware that this exists for sharing files, but I am interested in sharing links.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [share: ^2.0.4](https://pub.dev/packages/share) package and use the `text` property to show the text while sharing

```
Share.shareFiles("image.jpg", text: 'Hello your text goes here');
```

Comment: Ps: You can still do the same with the `share_plus` package

Comment: Do you know how to do this without needing to share a file, I am interested in sharing hyperlinks

Comment: You can use this package instead `flutter_share`